# Booted into black screen with a flashing under score

Tags: windows, boot, bios, hard-drive-failure, dell-optiplex

I am having a problem with my computer, a black screen with a flashing under score.

I was updating my system yesterday, then I let it update for awhile to complete and then switch it off. After working, I noticed it won't boot into windows. I let it load for like 30 mins and nothing happened. I don't have a recovery disk or anything, I installed it from the Microsoft official website.

Please help me, I got things to do.

Windows 8.1 Pro 32 bit

Answer (score 0):

You could try booting into windows safe mode by holding down the F8 key whilst booting up. Choose Safe-Mode with networking. 
If this is successful you can at least backup any data you require to an external drive and then you may be able to remove the windows update that the machine was attempting to install. Or restore back to an earlier state.

Comment: I tried it and it wasn't working, I bet it was the BIOS

Answer (score 0):

Download a Windows 8.1 Pro ISO. If you start the installation process, it should recognize the old installation, and it should offer to repair that install. Be careful not to do a reinstall, especially if it involves reformatting the disk.

If you don't feel confident, you can download an Ubuntu Live image, install it on USB or DVD, then run that. This way you can access your files, browse the internet. LibreOffice is a good replacement for MS Office, or you can open Office 365 in the browser. Make copies of files you edit to USB. LibreOffice may mess up the layout if that's important.

Use the opportunity to make a backup of your important files.

In the mean time you find a solution for the Windows setup.

Comment: Sure I'll try it but I bet it was the BIOS

Comment: Isn't it EFI by now, with secure boot and all? See http://www.fixedbyvonnie.com/2013/12/how-to-repair-the-efi-bootloader-in-windows-8/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to SPRBRN and TiO for answering my question. I managed to fix my problem!

This requires a rooted android device!

- Download DriveDroid
- Complete the following task
- Download any Linux Distribution
- Press on any Linux ISO and press writable
- Plug your USB to your computer
- Boot into your Device
- Complete the setup and your done!

You can install windows later